# There is no way to delete all cookies (Any domain) from a WebBrowser control in WP7. Is it true?

Tags: windows-phone-7

In my app I use WebBrowser control. User can visit http://mail.google.com then without logging out from google.com he visits http://twitter.com then http://abcd.com etc.

Now my requirement is to do the fresh start of the WebBrowser control and revisit those website and force the user to login again on those sites.

I tried so many options but I failed. I'm not able to find out exactly how can I delete all cookies from My Webbrowser control and do a fresh start.

**Can any body did the same successfully? Can you please share your code?**

Comment: I have the same problem, right now I just call the "logout" url from Google to fix this...

Comment: Then what about http://www.abcd.com it does not provide logout link separably!